# Select rows with a few same parameters

Tags: mysql, sql, django

I have 3 tables: `Student(id, username)`, `Skill(id, value)` and `StudentSkill(id, student_id, skill_id)`.
In django models they loook like that (short version):

```
class Student(models.Model):
    username = models.CharField(max_length = 50, unique = True)

class Skill(models.Model):
    value = models.CharField(max_length = 50, unique = True)

class StudentSkill(models.Model):
    student = models.ForeignKey(Student, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    skill = models.ForeignKey(Skill, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

I need to write a request, which returns a queryset of students with specific skills.

For example, I have the following data in database:

```
Student
id     | username
------ | ------
1      | user1
2      | user2
3      | user3

Skill
id     | value
------ | ------
1      | s1
2      | s2
3      | s3

StudentSkill
id     | student_id | skill_id
------ | ---------- | --------
1      | 1          | 1
2      | 2          | 1
3      | 2          | 2
4      | 3          | 1
5      | 3          | 2
6      | 3          | 3
```

`user1` has 1 skill: (`s1`)
`user2` has 2 skills: (`s1` and `s2`)
`user3` has 3 skills: (`s1`, `s2` and `s3`)

If I need to take students which have `s1` and `s2`, I must take `user2` and `user3`
If `s1` --> `user1`, `user2` and `user3`
If `s2` --> `user2` and `user3`
If `s1` and `s3` --> `user3`

I know 2 ways to solve this problem, but I think they are both bad.

First:

```
students = Student.objects.raw('''
    SELECT t1.* FROM (
        SELECT student.* FROM student
            INNER JOIN studentskill ON studentskill.student_id = student.user_id
            INNER JOIN skill ON skill.id = studentskill.skill_id
            WHERE skill.id = 1
        ) AS t1
        INNER JOIN studentskill ON studentskill.student_id = t1.user_id
        INNER JOIN skill ON skill.id = studentskill.skill_id
        WHERE skill.id = 2
    ''')
```

Second (I haven't checked this code, it may have bugs):

```
students = Student.objects.filter(studentskill__skill__id = 1
    ).select_related('studentskill', 'skill'
    ).only('student', 'studentskill', 'skill__id' )
students.filter(studentskill__skill__id = 2)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could use a group by and having distinct skill = 2

```
    select SELECT student.id, student.username
    FROM student
    INNER JOIN studentskill ON studentskill.student_id = student.user_id
    INNER JOIN skill ON skill.id = studentskill.skill_id
    WHERE skill.id in (1,2) 
    group by student.id, student.username
    havinge count(distinct studentskill.skill_id)= 2
```

Comment: It work. One question: `count(distinct studentskill.skill_id)= 2` - it counts number of coincidence skills for each student, and must be equal count of skill, which I use in `SELECT`, right? (I register just today and I have some trouble formatting)